# YII Validation rules , regex not working in YII

Tags: php, regex, validation, yii

I have the following rules in place for validation in YII , somehow the regex does't seem to work :

The rules in Yii modal :

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('password, email, username, password_confirmation', 'required'),
            array('password','match', 'pattern'=> '/^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,20}$/','message'=>"{attribute} should contain only alphanumeric and underscore."),
            array('email_conf', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('username, email, login_source', 'length', 'max'=>150),
            array('email','email'),
            array('password, password_confirmation', 'length', 'min'=>6, 'max'=>200),
            array("password", "compare", "compareAttribute" => "password_confirmation"),
            array('fb_id', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, username, email, password, login_source, fb_id, email_conf', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            array("password_confirmation, email_conf", "safe")
        );
    }
```

in the above code the line that concerns me is the following :

```
array('password','match', 'pattern'=> '/^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,20}$/','message'=>"{attribute} should contain only alphanumeric and underscore."),
```

the regex is such that it will accept  alphabets as the first character only and especial character
will not be accepted , spaces too won't be accepted .

now somehow even though i have used the right YII syntax ([check this on how to use regexes with YII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455022/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-yii))

the regex does't seem to work .

i created a simple PHP text case for this pattern :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $holder = $_POST['regex']; 
    $regrex = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,20}$/', $holder);

    if ($regrex) {
        echo "Match";
    }
    else {
        echo "Not match";
    }
}


?>

<form action="" method="post" >

    <input type="text" name="regex"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

and the regex works just fine !, so whats the problem in YII, even though i am correctly following the YII syntax ??

**EDIT :**

The corresponding label in the view file looks as follows :

```
<div class="">
       <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>
```

tenali.

**EDIT : 
CONTROLLER CODE :**

```
public function actionCreate()
       {
               $model=new User;

               // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
               // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

            if(isset($_POST['User']))
            {
            $username = $_POST['User'];
            if(isset($username['email'])) {
                $record=User::model()->find(array(
                  'select'=>'*',
                  'condition'=>'email=:email',
                  'params'=>array(':email'=>$username['email']))
              );
            }

            if($record===null){

                            $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];                       
                            $model->password = crypt($model->password,'salt');
                            $model->password_confirmation = crypt($model->password_confirmation,'salt');
                            //$model->password = $model->password;

                            if($model->save()){

                                // confirm mail send
                                $confirm_record=User::model()->find(array(
                          'select'=>'*',
                          'condition'=>'email=:email',
                          'params'=>array(':email'=>$username['email']))
                    );              

                    $to      = $username['email'];              
                    $subject = 'Confirm your Account';
                    $htmlBody = "Welcome and thank you for registering at Aaskar Pet Resort!<br>";
                    $htmlBody .= "Your account has now been created and you can log in by using your email address and password by visiting our website.<br>";
                    $htmlBody .= "<p><a style='text-decoration:none;' href ='".Yii::app()->request->hostInfo.''.$this->createUrl('site/confirmed',array('id'=> base64_encode($confirm_record['id'])))."'>Confirm your account</a></p>";
                    $htmlBody .= "<p>Upon logging in, you will be able to access other services including reservation for your pets, booking services and editing your account information.</p>";
                    $htmlBody .= "<p>Thanks,<br>Aaskar Pet Resort</p>";

                    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'From: <donotreply@purplefront.net>' . "\r\n";

                    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $htmlBody, $headers);
                     if($sent){
                        $message = $this->dynamicStatus('create_success');
                        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', $message);
                                        $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
                                    }

                                //Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Account has been created');
                                    //$this->redirect(array('site/index'));
                            }

                          }else{
                            $message = $this->dynamicStatus('email_exist');
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', $message);
                          }
               }

               $this->render('create',array(
                       'model'=>$model,
               ));
       }
```

here is a link of the code above on pastebin too , just incase it helps:

[Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/FUjrnZZF)

Comment: Do you have a label for your password in the view?, because if you don't have one, the validator will stuck by the `{attribute}`. You can try to change the message to `"Password should contain only alphanumeric and underscore."`.

Comment: Did you try to modify your message?

Comment: @Dinistro ur talking about the 2nd line in return array() right I.E. array('password','match', 'pattern'=> '/^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,20}$/','message'=>"{attribute} should contain only alphanumeric and underscore."), ??

Comment: Try to replace `array('password','match', 'pattern'=> '/^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,20}$/','message'=>"{attribute} should contain only alphanumeric and underscore."),` with `array('password','match', 'pattern'=> '/^[a-zA-Z]\w{5,20}$/','message'=>"Password should contain only alphanumeric and underscore."),`

Comment: @Dinistro just as a test case i tried doing this : array('password','match', 'pattern'=> '/^password/' ,'message'=>"password should contain only alphanumeric and underscore."),  and then entered "password" in the in the password feild , the test failed, so i am still unable to figure out where i am going wrong .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66923/discussion-between-dinistro-and-tenali-raman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you keep `password` parameter safe() for the `search` scenario only?

```
 array('id, username, email, password, login_source, fb_id, email_conf', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
```

You probably have to check the model scenario the from works with. Why not try to make these safe for all scenarios:

```
array('id, username, email, password, login_source, fb_id, email_conf', 'safe'),
```

### Update

From your controller/action code i see that right after you fetch the password field you perform password crypting. But you miss validation against the above model rule.
So if you want to do validation, do it before crypting:

```
 $model->attributes=$_POST['User']; 
 $model->validate();   // validation is performed                   
 $model->password = crypt($model->password,'salt');
 $model->password_confirmation = crypt($model->password_confirmation,'salt');
 ...
 // comment one or another of the following lines:
 $model->save(); // again validation is performed 
 $model->save(false); // no validation is performed when saving AR
```

If you want to escape validation in [`save()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail) with already crypted password, do this: `$model->save(false);`.

Comment: u mean instead of array('id, username, email, password, login_source, fb_id, email_conf', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'), i sould make it array('id, username, email, password, login_source, fb_id, email_conf', 'safe' ), ?? what would that really do ?

Comment: that would not restrict this rule to the only 'search' scenario. See here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/#hh1 Those attributes will be always `safe`.

Comment: pritty insightful  ! and thanks for ur answer and time , but my question was why was my pattern regex not working in YII where as it works just fine in plain PHP ?

Comment: @Tenali_raman, there might be some other issues frustrating regex application to the model form data. Would you put more info in your question (update/create controller actions and view form itself)?

Comment: @lgor Savinkin Edited.

Comment: @Tenali_raman, why don't you also post your yii controller action (update/create or other) where you receive and try to validate/save form parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66961/discussion-between-tenali-raman-and-igor-savinkin).